# MSSyncTable insert

Tags: ios, azure-mobile-services

I have a dictionary dict, the info is

```
(lldb) po dict
{
createdAt = "2016-05-25 06:29:16 +0000";
deleted = 0;
diskId = "f54b4bd9-694b-4856-8b8f-7f3afa18fd2e";
updatedAt = "2016-05-25 06:29:16 +0000";
userId = "4f119c15-2370-4ad7-bcbc-2cd4254b356e";
version = "1.0";
}
```

I call MSSyncTable insert function:

```
-(void)insert:(nonnull NSDictionary *)item completion:(nullable MSSyncItemBlock)completion;
```

the info is saved to local db successfully, but on the mobile service side, the received object don't have the info about version and updatedAt and createdAt, they are null, then mobile service return error to iOS app as below:

```
"{\"message\":\"The operation failed with the following error: 'A null store-generated value was returned for a non-nullable member 'Version' of type 'SaveOnPayService.Models.SOPUserStoresFavorite'.'.\"}"), NSLocalizedDescription=Not all operations completed successfully}
```

Is there anyone know what's going on here?

**Update:**
My server side code is like

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
    {
        TodoItem current = await InsertAsync(item);
        return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
    }
```

Do I need set createdAt, updateAt and version here?

**Updated:**
the console output in Mobile Service side:

w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='ExBenStoresFavorite', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerSelector.SelectController
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='ExBenService.Controllers.ExBenStoresFavoriteController', Operation=DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='ExBenService.Controllers.ExBenStoresFavoriteController', Operation=HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected action 'PostExBenStoresFavorite(ExBenStoresFavorite item)'', Operation=ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Value read='ExBenService.Models.ExBenStoresFavorite'', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Parameter 'item' bound to the value 'ExBenService.Models.ExBenStoresFavorite'', Operation=FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Model state is valid. Values: item=ExBenService.Models.ExBenStoresFavorite', Operation=HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableQueryFilter.OnActionExecutingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Operation=TableControllerConfigAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Will use same 'JsonMediaTypeFormatter' formatter', Operation=JsonMediaTypeFormatter.GetPerRequestFormatterInstance
w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Message='Selected formatter='JsonMediaTypeFormatter', content-type='application/json; charset=utf-8'', Operation=DefaultContentNegotiator.Negotiate
w3wp.exe Error: 0 : Message='The operation failed with the following error: 'A null store-generated value was returned for a non-nullable member 'Version' of type 'ExBenService.Models.ExBenStoresFavorite'.'.'
w3wp.exe Warning: 0 : Message='UserMessage='The operation failed with the following error: 'A null store-generated value was returned for a non-nullable member 'Version' of type 'ExBenService.Models.ExBenStoresFavorite'.'.'', Status=400 (BadRequest), Exception=System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException: Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.
   at Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Tables.EntityUtils.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.EntityDomainManager`1.<InsertAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.TableController`1.d__3.MoveNext()
Exception thrown: 'System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Is this mobile services or app service?

Comment: It's a Mobile service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the root cause. 
So I have a desktop which is also using EntityFramework and I use it to add data into my database. And the database is created by this Desktop App, So Version field in the database is Nullable, but if let mobile service create the database, then the Version field will be NOT NULL. that's the difference. so the fix is delete the database, can recreate through mobile service, it works now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to map the fields updatedAt, createdAt and version to the system properties, then you need to use the names `ms_createdAt`, `ms_updatedAt` and `ms_version`. Note that these cannot be set on the client, as they are set on the server side and returned to the client after the Push operation. To learn more about the Core Data model you need to use, see [Get Started with Offline Data Sync in Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started-offline-data/#review-core-data).

Also, to help in debugging, I recommend that you log your outgoing requests from your iOS client. See [Log outgoing requests in iOS native client](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#log-outgoing-requests-in-ios-native-client). You should log both the request and the response, and see if the system properties are actually being returned from your server.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to log the request and response to know more.

Comment: I add my server side code in the post. Do I need set updatedAt, createdAt and version  in that PostTodoItem method?

Comment: No, the server has them as part of the EntityData class. Your problem is probably that your CoreData model does not have the right field names.

Comment: (lldb) po response
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2a4d88fe0> { URL: https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/tables/xxxxx } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 198;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Thu, 26 May 2016 03:07:45 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }

Comment: based on the response, system properties are not actually being returned.

Comment: Do you have some tips on debugging the server side?  I use the demo app, TodoItem project, which has similar datamodel as me, but that code works. what I see is in datamodel, it's using version, createdAt and updatedAt, on server side, the parameter of function public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item), also has version, createdAt and updatedAt as null. But TodoItem can be inserted into DB successfully. I don't see any big difference between my code with TodoItem demo project,

Comment: except: 1. my Entity class use partial class way, means one file define my own field, another file inherit EntityData, and no any other data. 2. my project is using https

Comment: the TodoItem project can be found in Quick Start section of the mobile service on Azure portal.

Comment: Add Mobile Service log into the post, Can you help take a look at it?

Comment: @ExBen I think the problem is that you seem to have the wrong data type for the Version field on the server. Could you add your server-side data model?  For debugging the server, you can attach a debugger by following this guide: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#remote-debugging-net-server-sdk

Comment: @ExBen It's possible that Entity Framework does not like the partial class. Try merging into one class and see if that helps.

Comment: One thing I am guessing is my customized Table name and Schema name. default, the schema name is dbo, but I change it to BR. Will that impact the OR mapping?

Comment: Partial class does not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

In a Mobile Service, the submitted service fields must have a double-underscore - i.e.  `__deleted`, `__createdAt`, `__updatedAt` and `__version`.   These must have specific formats - specifically, `__deleted` must be a boolean and `__version` must be a byte-sequence.  In addition, you need an `id` field that is a GUID.